# Association (identification) of balls after stereo calibration and rectification using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, matlab-cvst, object-detection

first I will try to explane what I have to do and then I will ask my question to the problem.

My task is to detect small balls (2mm) in gelatine using two webcams.

The steps for detection are these:

1. Image taking using two webcams (position: 90 degree to each other)
2. Stereo calibration of each pair of images
3. Masking of the areas in the images which are not necessary to analyse
4. Rectification of each pair of images
5. Circle detection resulting in structure with the positions (x, y) of the center of each circle (in reality of each ball)
6. Association of the resulted position to get something like a 3D coordinate to know the position of the balls (this is my problem)

Now the problem (step 6.):
What possibilities are given to compute the 3D-coordinates of each center of the balls using the 2D-coordinates of the two images.

I'm searching here

http://de.mathworks.com/help/vision/stereo-vision.html

for ideas, but I hope you know some easy way and have some ideas.

I can not upload any images (because I'm new at stackoverflow)

Comment: You can upload images on other websites, give us the link and somebody here will upload it for you in your question. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a sample pair of stereo images from the webcam and a bit more information about the format of the detected circle data?

Comment: Here is the link, where you can find the images:

https://www.mediafire.com/folder/65f4nvgc8neu6/Camera 

InputW1.jpg and InputW2.jpg are used for the detection of the circles.

The properties which are checked are: Area, EquivDiameter, MajoAxisLength, MinorAxisLength and Perimeter (using the function regionprops from Toolbox).

Comment: All circles are detected and all the properties and the CENTROID of the circles are given after detection

Comment: Using the funtion matchFeatures results to one feature (see file OutputMatchFeaturesOfStereoImages.fig in MediaFire). Can this feature be used to get the correspondences of the other balls? I'm trying to make some computations.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example: [Depth Estimation from Stereo Video](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/depth-estimation-from-stereo-video.html). The example takes a pair images with a calibrated stereo camera, rectifies the images, detects a person, and gets the 3D coordinates of the centroid of the person.  You can do the same thing to find the balls.

1. Calibrate the cameras using the [Stereo Camera Calibrator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/stereo-camera-calibrator-app.html) app.
2. Take two images
3. Rectify the images using the `rectifyStereoImages` function
4. Compute stereo disparity using the `disparity` funciton
5. Get the 3D coordinates for every pixel using the `reconstructScene` funciton
6. Detect the balls in image 1
7. Look up the 3D coordinates of their centroids

Once you have the disparity and the dense reconstruction from `reconstructScene` there is no need to find correspondences between the images. `disparity` already did that for you.